# libgdx: where to put Gdx.gl.glClearColor()

Tags: opengl, libgdx, render

on all tutorials I have seen about libgdx, this method is placed in the renderloop, so every loop it is 'executed'.

Isn't it better to put it in render?

I thought it was the
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Doesn't 
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);

just set the color to clear the screen?

It works as expected if I put it in create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` *is* in the render loop.

And you're right: If you only want to call `glClearColor` once, you can put it in `create` or `resize`.

A single call to it per frame is negligible anyway. This isn't even worth your effort to cut and paste it to some other method. The examples you mentioned probably all put it in `render` right before `glClear` for clarity. Clarity is more important than performance if the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Thx, I thought it was something like that

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was the

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Doesn't

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
```

just set the color to clear the screen?

It works as expected if I put it in create

Comment: This should not have been posted as an answer, rather you should have edited your original post - just FYI ;)

Comment: First post on stackexchange... Thanks